# Is it possible to periodically repeat a dhcp request?

Tags: server, dhcp, dhclient

I have my ubuntu server set to get addresses from a dhcp server.
However, if that dhcp server is not currently active, the server will just stay with no address.

Is there some mechanism to periodically send dhcp requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron for that.

Open a console and as root type:

```
crontab -e
```

Insert a line that executes the dhclient

> 00 * * * *  dhclient eth0

This runs the command dhclient for the network card eth0 every hour (00)

You must change the time for the one you want, and the network card for yours.

If you want to know how cron works:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about this...what if I actually get an ip address: would I still keep polling the dhcp server?

Comment: Note that the iage you posted is not the format of `crontab -e` but of `/etc/crontab` which is different. User crontabs don't have the `user` field.

Comment: @Phate Then you should do something more elaborate like a script that checks if you have an ip address, if not then do the dhcp thing.

Comment: @terdon It was just an image to help him understand how cron works.